# Elementary proof of multiplicative property of determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Why LU decomposition is not used to give elementary proof of $\det (AB) = \det (A) \det (B) $  for square matrices?

It seems for any square  matrix $ A $, $ A = PLU$

P is permutation matrix, L lower triangular matrix, U upper triangular matrix.

Using elementary row operations :

$ \det (PB) = \det (B) \det (P) $,

$\det (LB) = \det (L) \det (B) $,

$\det (UB) = \det (U) \det (B) $

Regarding the last 2 identities: You can obtain $ LB $ by performing row additions to the matrix $ G=TB $,  where $ T $ is a diagonal matrix such that $ T_{ii} = L_{ii} $.

Starting from the last row, take each row of $ G $ and add multiples of rows above it to obtain the rows of $ LB $, this implies $ det (LB) = det (TB) =det (T) det (B)= det (L) det (B) $

Similar trick  works for $ UB $ by adding multiples of rows below a given row starting from the first row.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me why should $\det(LB)=\det L\det B$ or $\det (UB)=\det U\det B$

Comment: And how is it usually proved? The proof we were given in the class was basically a repeat of LU proof. (I guess it is always useful repeat such important stuff for students). But i personally love to think just of $\mathrm{det}$ as of constant by which volumes gets multiplied, then (at least for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$) this formula becomes obvious, and if we wish to extend it for other commutative rings, there is an algebraic trick.

Comment: Well, I wish I knew a proper answer which I could share with you, but I suspect that a proof involving LU decomposition might be considered *non-elementary*. There is no proof more elementary than one which uses little more than the definition of a determinant. See chapter 8 of https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~anne/linear_algebra/mat67_course_notes.pdf and chapter 6 of http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/primes2015/sols.pdf#page=372&zoom=100,0,369.

Comment: The usual intro proof uses elementary matrices/operations, which you would need anyway to prove your three identities.  Seems like you're inserting a middle-man.

Comment: @Gae.S. you can obtain $ LB $ by performing row additions to the matrix $ G=TB $ where $ T $ is a diagonal matrix such that $ T_{ii} = L_{ii} $

Comment: I agree with @Randall

Comment: Another proof: if you use the interpretation of $\det T$ as being the unique scalar such that ${\wedge}^n T = (\det T) \operatorname{id}$ (where $n$ is the dimension of the vector space $T$ operates on) then multiplicativity of $\det$ follows from functoriality of the antisymmetric product: ${\wedge}^n(T\circ U) = (\wedge^n T) \circ (\wedge^n U)$.

Comment: @Randall I'm just  suggesting it is simpler than attempting to expand the product $ AB $

Comment: As several commenters stated, there is a "standard" proof using elementary matrices. After defining the determinant in one of several ways, it is not difficult to argue (as the OP did also) that $\det(EB)=\det(E)\det(B)$ for each type of elementary matrix $E$. One then writes $A$ as a product of elementary matrices and applies this formula repeatedly. This is essentially the same proof as the OP proposes, but without grouping the elementary matrices into lower tri, upper tri, and permutations. Example write-up: https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/ProofDeterminantTheorem.pdf